# Excel скопировать столбец и приписать значения в скопированный

Tags: excel, vba

Всем привет. В таблице Excel есть столбец, в котором значения идут парами:

```
AAA
AAA
SSS
SSS
ZZZ
ZZZ
```

Мне необходимо сделать копию этого столбца и приписать справа цифры 1 и 2 через тире, чтобы получилось так:

```
AAA-1
AAA-2
SSS-1
SSS-2
ZZZ-1
ZZZ-2
```

Как это можно сделать проще всего?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=A1&"-"&СЧЁТЕСЛИ($A$1:A1;A1)
```

Вписать формулу в `A2`, протянуть по столбцу.

Не зависит от количества одинаковых значений. Также считает корректно в случае, когда одинаковые значения расположены не рядом.

Если формула не нужна: выделить полученные данные, копировать, **вставить как значения**

Comment: Большое спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант - формула (предположим, что данные расположены начиная с A1):

```
=A1 & " - " & ЕСЛИ(A2=A1;1;2)
```

Comment: Сокращаем :) `=A1&"-"&2-(A2=A1)`